# Field Name 'order' clashes with mysql with Zend_Db_table_Abstract?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework

unfortunately I created the table with a field name called `order`.

Is there a way to change the query builder to make sure the field name is encased in the ` (apostrophe's)

My query is as follows:

```
               $select = $this->select();
                $select->order('order DESC');
                $select->where('order < ?', $row->menu_id);
                $select->where('menu_id = ?', $row->menu_id);
```

The builder creates:

```
SELECT `menu_items`.* 
FROM `menu_items` 
WHERE (order < '1') 
AND (menu_id = '1') 
ORDER BY `order` DESC LIMIT 1
```

I would like it to create

```
SELECT `menu_items`.* 
FROM `menu_items` 
WHERE (`order` < '1') 
AND (menu_id = '1') 
ORDER BY `order` DESC LIMIT 1
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm no expert but according to the [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.9/en/zend.db.select.html)

> No quoting is applied to expressions given to the `where()` or `orWhere()` methods. If you have column names that need to be quoted, you must use `quoteIdentifier()` as you form the string for the condition.

There is an example of using `quoteIdentifier()` in the section "Adding Expression Columns":

```
$select = $db->select()
             ->from(array('p' => 'products'),
                    array('origin' =>
                              '(p.' . $db->quoteIdentifier('from') . ' + 10)')
                   );
```

So you need to do something like this:

```
$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$select = $this->select();
$select->order('order DESC');
$select->where($db->quoteIdentifier('order') . ' < ?', $row->menu_id);
$select->where('menu_id = ?', $row->menu_id);
```

Note that in the `order()` method,

> column names are quoted as identifiers, unless they contain parentheses or are an object of type `Zend_Db_Expr`.

so you don't have to do anything special there.

Comment: Thank you. You first need to get the default adapter: `$db = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();` and user `$db->quoteIdentifier('order')` as using the select gives `Unrecognized method 'quoteIdentifier()'`